# i was working on Linux using Command Line 'Putty' and i encountered this issue

Tags: linux, mapreduce, sqoop

```
$ sqoop help
Error: /home/hduser/sqoop/../hadoop-mapreduce does not exist!
Please set $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME to the root of your Hadoop MapReduce installation.
```

Comment: This question should be much more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Add the variable HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME to your .bashrc using some editor, for example [vim](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_06_02.html),

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

and add the following

```
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/home/hduser/sqoop/../hadoop-mapreduce
```

to your .bashrc and then type

```
$ exec bash
```

in your terminal to refresh your environment variables.